# Cannot connect to ODBC linked server in SSMS, but can in ODBC Data Sources

Tags: sql-server, odbc, servicenow

I have a SQL Server instance on a company server which is linked to ServiceNow via their ODBC driver.
As of this weekend, the connection fails when trying to test the connection under Linked Servers.
At first I thought it was a password issue, but I tried testing the connection via ODBC Data Sources and was able to log in fine.
I believe my IT department may have done something to block the traffic, is there anything else I can test to try and find the issue?

Comment: "the connection failed" doesn't help us help you. Find out what the connection error is. If you don't understand what that error is, then include it in your question.

Comment: Error given is:

The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)

Comment: maybe something with TLS 1.0, there were some recent updates that disabled that

Comment: I have some extra information.
I checked the provider settings for the linked servers as per ServiceNow's video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSxzmXYDQHU
Amended them as the video suggests caused the test connection to succeed, but now when I try and run a query I am getting a new error:

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW" reported an error. Access denied.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW".

Comment: Have you read ServiceNow's support document, [Troubleshooting Linked Servers](https://support.servicenow.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0538992)?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work again by unticking 'Allow in-process' in MSDASQL under Linked Servers --> Providers.

This is apparently what ServiceNow recommends for ODBC connections.

Full instructions in the below videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSxzmXYDQHU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtyMQsE8pvY